# Hibernate Exception: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException, while retrieving records from table

Tags: hibernate, hql

In Hibernate 4.0, i want to retrieve record from table using `session.createQuery("from dbemployee").list();`
but Hibernate is showing exception:

> Hibernate Exception: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: dbemployee is not mapped [from dbemployee]**

My POJO class is Employee

```
public class Employee implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private String empId;
private String empName;
private long empSalary;

public Employee() {
    super();
}

// getters and setters
```

}

My table `dbemployee` in Oracle 11g is:

```
dbemployee:
EMPID varchar2(20)
EMPNAME varchar2(20)
EMPSALARY number(11);
```

Employee.hbm.xml is

```
<hibernate-mapping>
  <class name="beanclass.Employee" table="dbemployee">

  <id name="empId" type="java.lang.String" column="EMPID">
  <generator class="assigned"></generator>
   </id>
   <property name="empName"  column="EMPNAME"  type="java.lang.String"/>
   <property  name="empSalary" column="EMPSALARY" type="java.lang.Long" />
  </class>

  </hibernate-mapping>
```

please help to solve this exception.
Thanks in advance

Comment: where is your connection setting file. you made mistake in connection

Answer (score 4):

Your query should be:

```
 session.createQuery("from Employee").list();
```

You have to use the class name in the query, not the table name.

Answer (score 3):

make your query as

```
 session.createQuery("from Employee").list();
```

or

```
session.createQuery("from beanclass.Employee").list();
```

In an ORM like Hibernate and JPA, when not dealing with native queries you shall use Object/Class names in your queries.

Comment: That's exactly what I wrote :-)